# Ansible ec2_* modules - filters option

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

Is there a way to define multiple values for the `filters` option on some of the `ec2_*` modules?

For example, the following play terminates all instances with the tag:Name Testing. How would I terminate all servers with `tag:Name Testing` or `tag:Name Staging`

```
ec2_instance:
    region: "{{ region }}"
    profile: "{{ lookup( 'env', 'AWS_PROFILE' ) }}"
    state: absent
    filters:
      tag:Name: Testing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each filter's value can be a list:

```
filters:
  'tag:Name':
    - Testing
    - Staging
```